# MATLAB: Using FZERO on a function which has a vector output

Tags: matlab, optimization, vector

I am working on my thesis and running in some programming problems in Matlab. I am trying to implement the ''golden Bisection Method'' to speed up my code. To this end, I've consulted the build in function FZERO.

So I am determining the difference between two vectors which are both (1x20).

```
Difference = Clmax_dist-cl_vec;
```

`Clmax_dist` comes from a semi-empirical method and `cl_vec` comes from the excecution of an external AVL.exe file.

Essentially, this difference depends only on one single variable `AOA` because the `Clmax_dist` vector is a constant. Hence, I am constantly feeding a new `AOA` value to the AVL.exe to obtain a new `cl_vec` and compare this again to the constant `Clmax_dist`.

I am iterating this until one of the element in the vector becomes either zero or negative. My loop stops and reveals the final `AOA`. This is a time consuming method and I wanted to use FZERO to speed this up.

However, the FZERO documentation reveals that it only works on function which has a scalar as input. Hence, my question is: How can I use FZERO with a function which has a vector as an output. Or do i need to do something totally different?

I've tried the following:

```
[Difference] = obj.DATCOMSPANLOADING(AOA);

fun=@obj.DATCOMSPANLOADING;
AOA_init = [1 20];
AOA_root = fzero(fun,AOA_init,'iter');
```

this gave me the following error:

```
Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Error in fzero (line 423)
while fb ~= 0 && a ~= b

Error in CleanCLmax/run (line 11)
AOA_root = fzero(fun,AOA_init,'iter');

Error in InitiatorController/moduleRunner (line 11)
        ModuleHandle.run;

Error in InitiatorController/runModule (line 95)
            obj.moduleRunner(ModuleHandle);

Error in RunSteps (line 7)
C.runModule('CleanCLmax');
```

The DATCOMSPANDLOADING function contains the following:

```
function [Difference] = DATCOMSPANLOADING(obj,AOA)

[Input]= obj.CLmaxInput;                                       % Creates Input structure and airfoil list
obj.writeAirfoils(Input);                                                  % Creates airfoil coordinate files in AVL directory
[Clmax_dist,YClmax,Cla_mainsections] = obj.Clmax_spanwise(Input);          % Creates spanwise section CLmax with ESDU method
[CLa] = obj.WingLiftCurveSlope(Input,Cla_mainsections);                    % Wing lift curve slope






[Yle_wing,cl_vec] = obj.AVLspanloading(Input,CLa,AOA);                      % Creates spanloading with AVL




         Difference = Clmax_dist-cl_vec;  

end
```

If I need to elaborate further, feel free to ask. And of course, Thank you very much.

Comment: Basically, you need to rewrite your functions so that you have an equation whose root you're trying to find.  It looks like you want to minimize one element in a vector, so perhaps something like  `foo = any(processed_vector <=0)`

Comment: Exactly! I am trying this right now. I also figured this out. Ill post my results when I am done. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fzero` indeed only works on scalars. However, you can turn your criterion into a scalar: You are interested in `AOA` where *any* of the elements in the vector becomes zero, in which case you rewrite your objective function to return two output arguments: `minDifference`, which is `min(Difference)`, and `Difference`. The first output, `minDifference` is the minimum of the difference, i.e. what `fzero` should try to optimize (from your question, I'm assuming all values start positive). The second output you'd use to inspect your difference vector in the end.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your comment. This approach seems to work fine and speeds up my code. You gave me my missing link. Never thought that turning my criterion in a single scalar would work. Thanks!