# MATLAB error using fzero function to solve the loop

Tags: matlab

My following code generates the plot of V and D values in figure 1. In the graph, the parabolas and straigh lines intersect, and I need to find the roots from the plot from a loop. So I tried to use fzero function, but the error appeared:

> Operands to the logical AND (&&) and OR (||) operators must be convertible to logical scalar values. Use the ANY or ALL functions to reduce operands to logical scalar values.
>
> Error in fzero (line 326)
> elseif ~isfinite(fx) || ~isreal(fx)
>
> Error in HW1 (line 35)
> x=fzero(fun,1);

My code is:

```
clear all; close all

W = 10000; %[N]
S = 40; %[m^2]
AR = 7;
cd0 = 0.01;
k = 1 / pi / AR;
clalpha = 2*pi;
Tsl=800; 
figure(1);hold on; xlabel('V');ylabel('D')
for h=0:1:8; 
    i=0;
    for alpha = 1:0.25:12
        i=i+1;
        rho(i)=1.2*exp(-h/10.4);
        cl(i) = clalpha * alpha * pi/180;
        V(i) = sqrt(2*W/rho(i)/S/cl(i));
        L(i) = 0.5 * rho(i) * V(i) * V(i) * S * cl(i);
        cd(i) = cd0 + k * cl(i) * cl(i);
        D(i) = 0.5 * rho(i) * V(i) * V(i) * S * cd(i);
        clcd(i) = cl(i)/cd(i);
        p(i) = D(i)*V(i);
        ang(i) = alpha;
        T(i)=Tsl*(rho(i)/1.2).^0.75;
    end
    figure(1); plot(V,D); hold on 
    plot(V,T);
end
fun = @(V) 0.5*V.*V.*rho.*S.*cd-T;
x=fzero(fun,1);
```

Probably, I should not use the fzero function, but the task is to find the roots of V from a plot (figure 1). There are parabolas and straight lines respectively.

Comment: Possibly a good candidate use-case for [`fminsearch()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html)

Comment: Possibly related: [MATLAB: Using FZERO on a function which has a vector output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34925169/8239061)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for `fzero(fun,x)`

> `fun`: Function to solve, specified as a handle to a scalar-valued function or the name of such a function. fun accepts a scalar `x` **and returns a scalar `fun(x)`**.

Your function does not return a scalar value for a scalar input, it always returns a vector which is not valid for a function which is being used with `fzero`.

Answer (score 0):

**1.-** Your codes doesn't plot `V` and `D`: Your code plots `D(V)` and `T(V)`

**2.-** `T` is completely flat, despite taking part in the inner `for` loop calculations with `T(i)=Tsl*(rho(i)/1.2).^0.75;`  as it had to be somehow modified.

But in fact it remains constant for all samples of `V`, constant temperature (°C ?), and for all laps of the outer `for` loop sweeping variable `h` within `[0:1:8]`.

The produced `T(V)` functions are the flat lines.

**3.-** Then you try building a 3rd function `f` that you put as if `f(V)` only but in fact it's `f(V,T)` with the right hand side of the function with a numerical expression, ***without a symbolic expression***, the symbolic expression that `fzero` expects to attempt zero solving.

In MATLAB **Zero finding has to be done either symbolically or numerically**.

A symbolic zero-finding function like `fzero` doesn't work with numerical expressions like the ones you have calculated throughout the 2 loops for `h` and for `alpha` .

Examples of function expressions solvable by `fzero` :

**3.1.-**

```
fun = @(x)sin(cosh(x));
x0 = 1;
options = optimset('PlotFcns',{@optimplotx,@optimplotfval});
x = fzero(fun,x0,options)
```

**3.2.-**

```
fun = @sin; % function
x0 = 3; % initial point
x = fzero(fun,x0)
```

**3.3.-** put the following 3 lines in a separate file, call this file `f.m`

```
function y = f(x)
y = x.^3 - 2*x - 5;
```

and solve

```
fun = @f; % function
x0 = 2; % initial point
z = fzero(fun,x0)
```

**3.4.-** `fzeros` can solve parametrically

```
myfun = @(x,c) cos(c*x);  % parameterized function
c = 2;                    % parameter
fun = @(x) myfun(x,c);    % function of x alone
x = fzero(fun,0.1)
```

**4.-** So since you have already done all the numerical calculations and no symbolic expression is supplied, it's reasonable to solve numerically, not symbolically.

To this purpose there's a really useful function called `intersections.m` written by Douglas Schwarz [available here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11837-fast-and-robust-curve-intersections?s_tid=srchtitle)

```
clear all; close all;clc

W = 10000; %[N]
S = 40; %[m^2]
AR = 7;
cd0 = 0.01;
k = 1 / pi / AR;
clalpha = 2*pi;
Tsl=800; 

figure(1);
ax1=gca
hold(ax1,'on');xlabel(ax1,'V');ylabel(ax1,'D');grid(ax1,'on');
title(ax1,'1st graph');
reczeros={}
for h=0:1:8; 
    i=0;
    for alpha = 1:0.25:12
        i=i+1;
        rho(i)=1.2*exp(-h/10.4);
        cl(i) = clalpha * alpha * pi/180;
        V(i) = sqrt(2*W/rho(i)/S/cl(i));
        L(i) = 0.5 * rho(i) * V(i) * V(i) * S * cl(i);
        cd(i) = cd0 + k * cl(i) * cl(i);
        D(i) = 0.5 * rho(i) * V(i) * V(i) * S * cd(i);
        clcd(i) = cl(i)/cd(i);
        p(i) = D(i)*V(i);
        ang(i) = alpha;
        T(i)=Tsl*(rho(i)/1.2).^0.75;
    end
 
    plot(ax1,V,D); hold(ax1,'on'); 
    plot(ax1,V,T);
    
    [x0,y0]=intersections(V,D,V,T,'robust');
    reczeros=[reczeros [x0 y0]];
    for k1=1:1:numel(x0)
        plot(ax1,x0,y0,'r*');hold(ax1,'on')
    end
    
end
```

[image]

Because at each pair `D(V)` `T(V)` there may be no roots, 1 root or more than 1 root, it makes sense to use a cell, `reczeros`, to store whatever roots obtained.

To read obtained roots in let's say laps 3 and 5:

```
reczeros{3}
=
55.8850  692.5504
reczeros{5}
=
23.3517  599.5325
55.8657  599.5325
```

**5.-** And now the 2nd graph, the function that is defined in a different way as done in the double `for` loop:

```
P = 0.5*V.*V.*rho.*S.*cd-T;

figure(2);
ax2=gca
hold(ax2,'on');xlabel(ax2,'V');ylabel(ax2,'P');grid(ax2,'on');
title(ax2,'2nd graph')
plot(ax2,V,P)
plot(ax2,V,T)

[x0,y0]=intersections(V,T,V,P,'robust');
for k1=1:1:numel(x0)
    plot(ax2,x0,y0,'r*');hold(ax2,'on')
end
```

[image]

```
format short
V0=x0
P0=y0
V0 =
86.9993
P0 =
449.2990
```